# How to call function written in .java class in IOS app

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, swift

I have a Java Class which has some functions which I want to consume from my IOS app.Is this possible on iOS?

I don't want to rewrite the whole logic written in java class in objective-C/Swift rather consume the already wriiten functions in java in my IOS app.I know this is quite possible upto some extent in OSX but I want to know how to do it in IOS?

Comment: Some times ago I was looking for possibility of linking Java library into Swift or Objective-C but with no results. The best option for me was to use Java framework for whole application such as RoboVM: https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm

Comment: Thanks.Will check this out